# Removing sequence of numbers from Readline with Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following sample string:

```
   string s = Console.ReadLine();
   s= {6} {7613023456148 } {7.040 } {56780} {Sample String}
```

How do I achieve the following with regex or something similar:

- Remove all numbers in a line that start with 7 and are 13 digits long.
- Remove all decimal numbers.

**Output**

```
s = {6} {56780} {Sample String}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the captured string use following regex with an empty string :

```
7\d{12}|\d\.\d+
```

But Note that if your numbers are within `{}` you need :

```
\b{\s*7\d{12}\s*}\b|\b{\s*\d+\.\d+\s*}\b
```

See demo https://regex101.com/r/dL1vF4/1

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use `\d+.\d+` (Plus on both of them), and also wrap the regex between a `\b` (Word boundary).

Comment: @OrelEraki Indeed, I missed `+`, but `\b` was a good point! thanks for attention!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for this regex:

```
var s = "{6} {7613023456148 } {7.040 } {56780} {Sample String}";
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"\s*{(?:\s*7[0-9]{12}\s*|\d+\.\d+\s*)}", string.Empty);
Console.WriteLine(s); // ==> "{6} {56780} {Sample String}"
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/wE8O5T)

**REGEX** matches 2 alternatives inside `{...}` that is preceded with optional whitespace (`\s*`):

- `\s*7[0-9]{12}\s* - optional whitespace followed with`7`, then 12 digits and optional whitespace
- `\d+\.\d+\s*` - 1 or more digits, a `.` decimal separator, again 1 or more digits, and optional whitespace.

Since all your values are inside `{...}`, you need no word boundaries.